# Shared file location in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Is there a way to create a file in one app (which I can currently do) close the app, then open a different app (also made by me) and open that file.

At the moment, the only way I can save is in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder but that makes it local to the first app.

I looked at using ms-appdata:/// etc. to try and point to the 1st apps local folder but couldn't work it out.

I'm developing a universal app targeted at 8.1 in Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't think the concept of shared file exists in WP8.1. All you can do is store the file in cloud and then access it